# Is it possible to customize the asp .net mvc 3 generated Views?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been using asp.net mv3 via vs 2010 for quite a while now, also the default views and actions generated when creating a controller are very helpful. However lately, i found it redundant to keep on adding the same stuff in the generate view, for example, i have to place "btn" class names on links and button, since im using a 3rd party css library. So, i was wondering if it was possible to customize the generated views so that i wouldn't have to add them anymore after generation of the view?

image --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Aiz.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible to customize the built in TT templates which used fot the scaffolding.

Here is a good how to: [Modifying the default code generation/scaffolding templates in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx)

If you are more into scaffolding the [MVC Scaffolding project](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) could be also interesting for you.